# Getting odd numbers from the array

Tags: perl

To get the odd numbers from the array i got this code but didn't understand one syntax. Code is as below

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

# initialize an array
my @array = qw(3 4 5 6 7 8 9);

my @subArray = ();
  foreach (@array) {
  push @subArray, $_ if $_ & 1;
}
print "@subArray\n";
# displays: 3 5 7 9
```

What is "if $_ & 1"
This is working. But i didn't get the syntax "if $_ & 1".

Similarly grep can be used like "my @subArray = grep $_ & 1, @array; "

Please help me understanding the syntax

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Bitwise-And

Comment: @Sean: Thanks for the reply. But it is still unclear to me. I went to the link but didn't get. It would be appreciable if you explain it

Comment: Make sure to accept an answer if one worked for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The logic:** 
If you do an AND operation between an odd number and 1 (in binary, of course), the result obtained will always be 1.

**How it works:**
The above code looks for an odd number by performing a bitwise AND operation between the array element and the number 1. If the operation results in "true", it is inserted into the final array (@subArray). The $_ here is referring to the individual element of the original array which is accessed during iteration.

Here's how the bitwise AND operation works.

1. Suppose you want to determine if 3 is an odd number (binary for 3 -> 0011).
2. As per this code, you are performing a bitwise AND with 1, the binary for which, is 0001.
3. the AND operation takes place between 0011 and 0001, and since it is **bitwise**, each **bit** is AND'ed with the corresponding bit of the other.
4. Here's how it happens,
   Binary for 3      :      0  0  1  1
   Binary for 1      :      0  0  0  1
   **Result of AND   :      0  0  0  1**
5. As you can see, the final result is 1, which is also the lowest order bit (first bit starting from right). Hence the expression `if $_ & 1;` results in "true" and the number is inserted into the `subArray`, via the `push` operation.

Answer (score 4):

The structure of that line is:

```
<statement> if <condition>
```

where `<statement>` is `push @subArray, $_` and `<condition>` is `$_ & 1`.

The expression `$_ & 1` is 1 or 0 according to whether the lowest-order bit of `$_` is set or not. If it is 1 (which is a `true` value in Perl), then `push @subArray, $_` is executed; otherwise it is 0 (a `false` value in Perl) and the statement is skipped.

Comment: "the lowest-order bit of $_" --> what is lowest order bit

Comment: How it is working to find odd numbers from the array . Rest all syntax including "push" is clear

Comment: @Nitesh - That would be the bit corresponding to 2^0 in the binary expansion of `$_`. That bit being set is equivalent to `$_` having an odd value. This is a nearly-universal test for whether a value is even or odd.

Answer (score 4):

**What is** `$_ & 1`?

This expression segregates the low-bit, and only the numbers with low-bit set (odd numbers)

- `$_` is the default variable, in this case each array element
- `&` is binary AND operator/bitwise string operator (returns its operands together bit by bit)
- `1` is just one
- See `perldoc perlop` (Multiplicative Operators) and [bit-hacks](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/low-level-bit-hacks-you-absolutely-must-know/) for further explanation.

Alternatively, you can parse your even/odd using the modulo operator `%`.

Using a `for` loop.

```
my @odd;
for (@array) {
   push @odd, $_ if $_ % 2;
}
```

Using `map`

```
my @odd = map { $_ % 2 ? $_ : () } @array;
```

Or even an `array slice` using `grep`..

```
my @odd = @array[grep { ! ($_ % 2) } 0 .. $#array];
```

Answer (score 3):

The meaning of `$_ & 1` has already explained above, but in this case, I believe it would be more maintainable if you write like:

`my @oddArray = grep { $_ % 2 != 0 } @array;`

Comment: Why `!= 0`? I don't get it.

Comment: @Hynek-Pichi-Vychodil I know it's a kind of redundant, but I just want to indicate explicitly that we only collect odd numbers with `grep` in this example, although without the `!= 0` it still does the same thing.

Comment: [Truth and Falsehood](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Truth-and-Falsehood) says that *The number 0, the strings '0' and "" , the empty list () , and undef are all false in a boolean context. All other values are true.* `$_ % 2` evaluates only into 0 or 1 so adding `!= 0` is just waste in many ways including reader's brain capacity.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply?

```
my @subArray = grep {$_ & 1} @array;
```

And why you initialize array using `qw(3 4 5 6 7 8 9)` when you need numbers?

```
my @array = (3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
```

is much better. You are just wasting CPU time and memory and more importantly misleading reader of your code. Which points me out to more obvious code.

```
my @subArray = grep {$_ % 2} @array;
```

The performance difference will be negligible and it is far more obvious what is going on.